# Preventing ibid in individual cases

Tags: citing

If one wants to mark a disagreement with someone, one might do `\footnote{Pace \cite[35]{smith88}.}`.  How would one make sure this would not turn into 'Pace ibid.'?  (Assume one wants ibid. in other situations.)

Comment: How are you generating your citations? Can you provide a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: Assuming you use `biblatex` you might want `\citereset`, `\mancite` or `\makeatletter\blx@ibidreset\makeatother`before the citation.

Comment: Did any of my suggestions help you? If not it would be really helpful to know which bibliography package you use (do you use `biblatex`, `natbib`, `cite`, ...) and which bibliography style you use. An [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) would help us get started and allows us to test our solutions against your setup.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If not, can you give a bit more context and explain how it was not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `biblatex` there are several ways to do this.

The least intrusive, but least elegant method is to use

```
\makeatletter\blx@ibidreset\makeatother
```

just before your citation. This will only reset the 'ibidem' mechanism. Of course you can wrap this up into a macro that does not need `\makeatletter...\makeatother` to make this less clumsy.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ibidreset}{\blx@ibidreset}
\makeatother
```

You could also use `\mancite`. This command resets not only the 'ibidem' mechanism, but also the trackers for 'idem', 'loc. cit.' and 'op. cit.'.

Finally, you could use `\citereset`. This command resets all the trackers reset by `\mancite` (but in a slightly more resolute way; it ignores the context setting), it will also reset the list of 'seen citations' for the `\ifciteseen` test.